# Format text ouput

Tags: powershell, text, format, output, tabular

When I run my script I get results that look like this

```
Computername                                          IPAddress                                             Date                                                
------------                                          ---------                                             ----                                                
testdns100                                            10.50.21.210                                          11/15/2013 14:00
```

When I do a write-host or something similar, since I want to send the result out via email I get an output like this

```
@{Computername=testdns100; IPAddress=10.50.21.210; Date=11/15/2013 14:00}
```

Whats the best way for me to keep the output in the table format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For email, the easist way I know is to run it through Format-Table, then Out-string:

```
$Body = $Objects | Format-Table | Out-String
```

Comment: Would it matter if the $Objects was a function?  Just tried this and got the same bad result.

Comment: Actually when I ran your code through the body of my email instead of write-host it worked although my second line is a bit off